# System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a problem on VB.Net which a part of my system has a error. It doesn't save the date thus generating this error. The format was identical to the output on the datetime Picker.

```
    ElseIf Date.Parse(expirationDTP.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) <= Date.Parse(Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) Then
        MsgBox("Select the expiration date of the stock!")
```

This is an image of the output.

[Date Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQhxR.png)

Thanks!

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour] to get the most from the site - like more answers than downvotes

Comment: Hello! Thanks but it does not work for me.

Comment: Please define "does not work" - it is a very ambiguous term. What are you expecting it to do and what does/doesn't it do? Seeing as it's an `ElseIf` have you checked that it doesn't pass the initial `If` or other preceding `ElseIf`s? Because as illustrated by this simple test, it most definitely should work: http://dotnetfiddle.net/qPWwzy

Comment: Also see the **EDIT** part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`expirationDTP.Value` and `Date.Now` already are of type `Date`. Why are you converting them into strings only to convert them ***back*** to `Date` objects?

Just compare them directly:

```
ElseIf expirationDTP.Value <= Date.Now Then
```

For future reference, the actual error occurs because `Date.Parse()` tries to use the current system's cultural settings to parse the date. If you need to parse a specific date format you should use [**`Date.ParseExact()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Date.ParseExact("01/20/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Try comparing the `Date` properties of the two `Date` objects:

```
ElseIf expirationDTP.Value.Date <= Date.Now.Date Then
```

If it still doesn't work you're going to have to check if it's any preceding `ElseIf` or the initial `If` that gets executed instead. As you haven't shown any more code than that there's not much more I can do.